# Currency resolver - Cache problem on platform.sh

Tags: commerce

I'm using currency resolver (commerce) based on cookie to switch currencies in block (have a custom field for usd price in price variant). Locally everything's work fine (apache) but on platform.sh switcher block is not working.I think it has to do with some server caching (internal cache is disabled in drupal). I tried to add some yml config on platform.sh for disabling cache but without result. Did anyone have similar experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Blocks have cache tags, and cache contexts. You'll probably need to disable caching for that block by setting #cache max-age to 0.

Comment: But Internal Page Cache module is disabled, that should be related with the caching blocks right? As I said, locally on my machine everything's work fine.

Comment: No, block caching happens automatically. Drupal has many, many layers of caching. Page caching is done at the page level. Oh, note that I'm talking about Drupal 8 though. Just realized you didn't specify a version.

Comment: Yes, it's d8 I'm using. But how is that on my local machine it works (apache) and on platform (nginx) is not working? Same drupal configuration

Comment: Because your local machine and the production server have different settings somewhere apparently. That's not the kind of thing that can be debugged on Drupal answers.

Comment: Hi, completely understand what you are talking about. That was initially my question, did anyone have similar problem on platform.sh with currency resolver...
Thanks Jaypan

Comment: Production servers almost always use more caching than non-production servers. Otherwise, production sites would be too slow to use. That is why sometimes you need to either invalidate cache tags, or disable caching for a block altogether. Disabling caching for a whole site is overkill - like killing a mosquito with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I found solution and wrote the answer. Thanks again for your help Jaypan

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add cookie to routes.yml file in .platform folder and than push it to the platform branch. After that currency resolver will work.